# How can I change how my WordPress theme displays categories? I want to display subcategories under parent category

Tags: wordpress, categories, wp-list-categories

I'm trying to hide sub-categories under categories, but I'm not able to. I'm looking to create a follow menu. How can I do that?

```
add_action('zigcy_lite_product_cat_menu','zigcy_lite_add_browse_categories_nav_menu_items');
if ( ! function_exists( 'zigcy_lite_add_browse_categories_nav_menu_items' ) ) {
    function zigcy_lite_add_browse_categories_nav_menu_items() {

     if ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) )
        return;

    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat');
    $count = count($product_categories);                
    ?>
    <div class="browse-category-wrap">
        <div class="browse-category">
            <i class="lnr lnr-menu"></i>
            <?php esc_html_e('Shop by Gender','zigcy-lite'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="categorylist">
           <ul>
            <?php 
            foreach( $product_categories as $product_category   ) {
                $cat_name = $product_category->name;
                $cat_id = $product_category->term_id;
                ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_term_link($cat_id));?>"><?php echo esc_html($cat_name); ?> </a></li>
                <?php } ?>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
}
```

Menu shown here:

[image]

Comment: I see your code, but I don't understand what the problem is... what does your code display?  Are you getting the unordered list of categories and now you need to learn how to create an accordion effect?  Or are you not getting the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Check the get_terms reference at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

You can pass the "parent" argument to only get the top level categories:

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => true, 'parent' => 0 );
$product_categories = get_terms('product_cat', $args);

foreach ($product_categories as $term) {
    echo '<li><a href="/your-category-base-url/' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('Category %s', 'zigcy-lite'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . ' ('.$term->count.')</a></li>';
}
```